# How to logout of Facebook using javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Consider the following 2 Scenario:

1) I have a Facebook **Logout & Login Button** on my application(say myApp) and i login into Facebook using **Login Button**(it prompts me facebook login dialogue and login is successful). Now i open a new browser tab and go to **www.facebook.com**, It opens up my Facebook account. Now i come to my application(myApp) and click the Facebook **Logout button** and i see that i am able to log out of **www.facebook.com**.....This works fine no doubt.

Now consider my second scenario

2) I open two tabs one is **myApp** and second is **www.facebook.com**. I login into my Facebook account from **www.facebook.com** first. now i come to **myApp** and refresh it and hit Facebook **Logout Button**. This time i am not logged out from **www.facebook.com**.

Considering that the Facebook **Logout button** on **myApp** is implemented using Javascript SDK  `FB.logout(function(){})` i have my Facebook **appId** which is configured correctly.

**So my Big Question is**:

Is it possible to logout a user from www.facebook.com without considering **appId** which is required in javascript SDK config ??

**or**

Is it possible to invalidate a **User Access Token** in ordered to kill facebook brower session.

Comment: You can only log the user out of Facebook, if you have a valid user access token. The JS SDK caches the result of the login status check, so you might need to force it to re-check (can be done using `FB.getLoginStatus` with second param set to `true`.)

Comment: Check [tihs link](https://gist.github.com/heldrida/6232556). it might help you.

Comment: yes it does give me the correct Access_Token, **But how to logout a user**. If the user was logged in by using **appId** then we can log him out. but if the session was set by logging in via www.facebook.com then how to log out user programatically ??

Comment: @PHPExpert & @CBroe I am aware of the fact that if **Access_Token** is generated with the help of **appId** then we can log out via `FB.logout();` but if the login is initiated via Facebook App(i.e. without **appId**) then you don't have control over **Access_Token**

Is there any work around to invalidate **Access_Token**

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “control over” the access token. If the user has previously connected to your app, then you will automatically get a fresh access token from the JS SDK – but that requires it to check the current login status, and as I explained that result might be cached. So you’ll have to _force_ it to check again, circumventing the cache.

Comment: Please do the following to understand my problem. I really appreciate your efforts @CBroe
1) Create a simple page with Javascript SDK and make LogIn & LogOut button.
2) open new tab with **www.facebook.com** and log in into it.
3) Come back to your page and hit Logout button with FB.logout();. It wont let you logout.

Comment: No, if anything, you should provide a working example yourself. // Besides, I am not really sure if that “problem” here actually is one – the situation you’re describing seems rather construed, and not like a scenario that would happen that often in the real world.

Comment: @AmitPrabhuParrikar, what you describe is the intended mechanics, and you can't force a logout unless the login was also tied to your app.

Comment: @SeanKinsey thanks a lot. Yes thats right. you have control over Access_Token only if it is created with your app.